# Redirect mapping media item in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, pipelines, redirect

I have already asked the question related to redirect mapping of `media item` in `Sitecore SXA`. This question is related to get this functionality though custom code or pipeline. I have not found any relevant material for this on internet as this is not provided by Sitecore by default.

Could someone assist me how I can achieve this functionality through custom code or through redirect mapping `pipelines`?

Comment: Did you see this https://www.coreysmith.co/sxa-media-and-layout-not-found/ 
In this link, it has information about the whole process. You can try this.

Comment: As you mentioned, you have already asked this question. If you want to further clarify the answer you want, please edit the original question rather than post a near identical one.